# AWS DynamoDB Stream triggering 2 (almost) identical events for a single change on a single record

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I've got a DynamoDB table set up with a Stream using the "new and old" option.

I then create a Lambda and set a trigger for this DynamoDB table.

If I make a single change to an item in the DynamoDB table, I immediately see a log entry for the lambda (i.e. it's working as expected). Then, after refreshing the Lambda log, I see a SECOND entry for the exact same Event. If I do some console logging, I get the following output:

```
{
  eventID: '993816ae020b3e179be01be3b6483818',
  eventName: 'MODIFY',
  eventVersion: '1.1',
  eventSource: 'aws:dynamodb',
  awsRegion: 'us-west-2',
  dynamodb: {
    ApproximateCreationDateTime: 1583960109,
    Keys: { Guid: [Object], Timestamp: [Object] },
    NewImage: {
      Brand: [Object],
      'aws:rep:updatetime': [Object],
      EntryType: [Object],
      RequestId: [Object],
      KnownClients: [Object],
      Guid: [Object],
      'aws:rep:deleting': [Object],
      EntryCount: [Object],
      Timestamp: [Object],
      'aws:rep:updateregion': [Object]
    },
    OldImage: {
      Brand: [Object],
      'aws:rep:updatetime': [Object],
      EntryType: [Object],
      RequestId: [Object],
      KnownClients: [Object],
      Guid: [Object],
      'aws:rep:deleting': [Object],
      EntryCount: [Object],
      Timestamp: [Object],
      'aws:rep:updateregion': [Object]
    },
    SequenceNumber: '156626400000000015112302820',
    SizeBytes: 604,
    StreamViewType: 'NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES'
  },
  eventSourceARN: 'arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123456789123:table/dynamotabletest/stream/2020-02-07T19:24:06.547'
}
```

and here's the output for the SECOND event which is logged 1 second after the first event:

```
{
  eventID: 'bdc5295c3eabf7e5fb036a9cbd4fcca9',
  eventName: 'MODIFY',
  eventVersion: '1.1',
  eventSource: 'aws:dynamodb',
  awsRegion: 'us-west-2',
  dynamodb: {
    ApproximateCreationDateTime: 1583960109,
    Keys: { Guid: [Object], Timestamp: [Object] },
    NewImage: {
      Brand: [Object],
      'aws:rep:updatetime': [Object],
      EntryType: [Object],
      RequestId: [Object],
      KnownClients: [Object],
      Guid: [Object],
      'aws:rep:deleting': [Object],
      EntryCount: [Object],
      Timestamp: [Object],
      'aws:rep:updateregion': [Object]
    },
    OldImage: {
      Brand: [Object],
      'aws:rep:updatetime': [Object],
      EntryType: [Object],
      RequestId: [Object],
      KnownClients: [Object],
      Guid: [Object],
      'aws:rep:deleting': [Object],
      EntryCount: [Object],
      Timestamp: [Object],
      'aws:rep:updateregion': [Object]
    },
    SequenceNumber: '156626500000000015112302880',
    SizeBytes: 604,
    StreamViewType: 'NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES'
  },
  eventSourceARN: 'arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123456789123:table/dynamotabletest/stream/2020-02-07T19:24:06.547'
}
```

I did a text compare, and the ONLY difference is the eventID and the SequenceNumber.

Anyone know what's happening here?

Here's my code for the lamdba that listens for a trigger event:

```
'use strict';

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var parse = AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.output;
const firehose = new AWS.Firehose({ region: 'us-east-2' });

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var fireHoseInput = [];

    event.Records.forEach((record) => {

        console.log(record);

        if ((record.eventName == "INSERT")||(record.eventName == "MODIFY")) {
            fireHoseInput.push({ Data: JSON.stringify(parse({ "M": record.dynamodb.NewImage })) });
        }
    });
    console.log('Firehose Input: ', fireHoseInput);
    var params = {
        DeliveryStreamName: 'test-dynamodb-stream',
        Records: fireHoseInput
    };
    if(fireHoseInput.length != 0)
    {
    firehose.putRecordBatch(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else console.log(data);           // successful response
    });
    }
    else
        {
            console.log("No data to transmit");
        }
    callback(null, `Successfully processed records.`);
};
```

Any ideas as to why a single change to a record in my DynamoDB table is triggering 2 identical events in the lambda that's listening to that DynamoDB Stream?

**UPDATE**: I did a little console logging earlier in the lambda to get the raw data from the DynamoDB Stream event that my lambda is listening for with the trigger. Here's what I found in the FIRST event that fires: `NewImage` shows the update I made to a field, while `OldImage` shows the old value in the field.

Then in the SECOND event that's firing, that field I changed is showing as the same newly updated value in both `NewImage` and `OldImage`, but the only field that changed is `aws:rep:updatetime`. So presumably what is happening is that the change to the data field is captured in the first event, then the second event no longer cares about the change to that data field, but updates the replication timestamp which causes the DynamoDB stream to fire a second event with the same data (except now the `aws:rep:updatetime` is changed). So sounds like I need to update my lambda to ignore that 2nd event if the only field that changed was `aws:rep:updatetime` (which I don't care about in my data flow). Thoughts?

Comment: According to the docs, stream events should only appear once. Could you show us the code that inserts/update events into the table? I would first check that each record is only written once.

Comment: I made an update to my original post, looks like `aws:rep:updatetime` is the only field that is changing in the 2nd event that fires... See above for details!

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer here: [Global Table replication stream event issues](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=887485&#887485)

Looks like the DDB Stream Lambda needs to check on the `aws:rep:updatetime` field on the incoming `event.Records[record.dynamodb.newImage]` and `event.Records[record.dynamodb.oldImage]`, and if it's the same, then process the record. If it's different, then discard the record.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Would you mind adjusting your question to contain "Global Table" if you're using those?

Comment: Is this still an issue with Global Tables 2019? I've been testing some setups looking for this duplicate record, but haven't observed it.

Comment: Update: 
As per [the update doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/V2globaltables_upgrade.html), 
"DynamoDB global tables version 2019.11.21 (current) introduces the following changes in behavior:
...
DynamoDB Streams publishes only one record (instead of two) for each write.
..."

Answer (score 0):

I believe its still the same.

I have also put a check for both of the images to exit the lambda early for 2nd trigger.

However, i found that instead of comparing `oldImage` and `newImage` as a whole,
In the first call, `aws:rep:updateTime` field is same in both of the images
While in the replication trigger(2nd call), `aws:rep:updateTime` is different.

The point is, instead of comparing the json bodies completely, if we can check only one field, that may save some milliseconds of time and some MBs of space in every other trigger in lambda from dynamoDB.

Let me know your thoughts