# DynamoDB Streams and Global Tables - duplicate state changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Hi everyone I looked through similar questions but no one asked a similar question.

I have a setup of DynamoDB with global tables in active-passive mode (this is an existing situation, so please don't ask why) so basically, the second region is used only for data high availability (in case the main region goes down).

A picture says more than a thousand words, so I start with one:
[image]

I have an application in Region 1 that writes to DynamoDB global tables (in region 2 I have only a passive copy of DynamoDB ).

Also in region 1, I have a mechanism that listens to DynamoDB streams and takes some action when the object stored changes its state from A to B (create some object then update some object).

Now what I'm experiencing is that this action happens twice. My question is whether my thinking is correct:

- Application creates an object in state A in region 1 very fast (and emits streams event), region 2 takes a longer time
- Then update request comes in immediately and changes state to B in region 1 (and emits streams event)
- Additional action is taken as we listen to region 1 streams and object change state from A to B.
- Then region 2 confirms first write and global tables mechanism updates region 1 state again to state A (and emits streams event)
- Then region 2 confirms second write and global tables mechanism updates region 1 state again to state B (and emits streams event)
- Additional action is taken again as again we detect state change from A to B

Currently, I have no proof that this is what exactly happens but after looking into application logs I'm sure we receive region 1 streams update 2 times (2x A->B).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60646877/aws-dynamodb-stream-triggering-2-almost-identical-events-for-a-single-change-o suggested that DynamoDB Global yields an additional record for the replication.

Comment: So unfortunately no, we were unable to fix this situation so we moved to another solution where we divided a single table into 3 tables and never do updates, only inserts this way we can have multiple regions writes + global tables and no duplicate in DDB streams